# More ways to display Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

While learning Pandas, the main tool I am using is Jupyter Notebook. It is nested with great compatibility on displaying Dataframe properly, but question raises here. If I wish to display Dataframe without Jupyter Notebook, what will be the good tools?

For now, console is too primitive, and logging into a csv/xlsx/whatever-type file all has their own problem. GUI might be an option, but I would put it at the last place, considering the hidden workload of developing it.

Comment: Displaying dataframe in console is enough to read, I think.

Comment: Someone made this great one, [rich-dataframe](https://github.com/khuyentran1401/rich-dataframe), for most terminals now, it is based on [Will Mcguggan's awesome Rich library](https://github.com/Textualize/rich). And there's lots of alternatives for inside Jupyter than the default handling, too.

Comment: [D-Tale](https://github.com/man-group/dtale) or [bamboolib](https://github.com/tkrabel/bamboolib) or [nteractio data explorer in JupyterLab's data explorer](https://twitter.com/SShanabrook/status/1182441342082965504) or [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Tabular_Datasets.html) or [Jupyter Bifrost](https://github.com/jupytercalpoly/jupyter-bifrost) or [ipyregulartable](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/ipyregulartable#pandas-data-model) or [Jupyter DataTables](https://medium.com/@marekermk/take-a-better-look-at-the-pandas-dataframes-a8d6613a46a)

Comment: Or [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some useful tools:

- Panel

  - https://panel.holoviz.org/#
- bokeh

  - https://bokeh.org/
- voila

  - https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila

In the following article you can find more useful tools:

- https://medium.com/@marcskovmadsen/i-prefer-to-use-panel-for-my-data-apps-here-is-why-1ff5d2b98e8f

Answer (score 1):

You can try [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) or for graphical illustration [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). If you want to stay in console [plotext](https://github.com/piccolomo/plotext)